# How to specify URL deeplink android manifest

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, android-deep-link

Problem is I don't know how to make deep link from this link "my.app//id=819"

I tried some variations of data but can't understand the path Pattern

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data 
        android:scheme="my.app" 
        android:host="id" 
        android:pathPattern="=.*"/>
```

expected is to lunch intent and take the value of id

Comment: Is that link an external link or an internal app link? I think `id=819` is more of a parameter than a host

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like `my.app//host?id=819`, right?

You build the intent-filter around `my.app//host`, do not include the parameters.

[Add intent filters for incoming links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="my.app"
          android:host="host" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then once inside the activity, you can parse for the parameters, [Read data from incoming intents](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#handling-intents):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

From `data`, you can use [Uri#getQueryParameter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)) to get the `819` from the `id`:

```
String id = data.getQueryParameter("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `<intent-filter>` you specify the urls that your activity is supposed to handle. Once the system detects an activity in your application is able to handle the url, it opens that activity and you are able to fetch the data in `Extra` or `.getData()` object.

In your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="My app preview">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.myapp.com/api/id"
                android:pathPrefix="/api/" <!-- optional, you can skip this field if your url doesn't have prefix-->
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="www.myapp.com/api/id"
                android:pathPrefix="/api/" <!-- optional, you can skip this field -->
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
       Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           handleExtra(getIntent());
       }

       // If your app is in opened in background and you attempt to open an url, it 
       // will call this function instead of onCreate()
       @Override
       protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
           super.onNewIntent(intent);
           setIntent(intent);
           handleExtra(getIntent());
       }

       private void handleExtra(Intent intent) {
           String myID = intent.getData().getLastPathSegment();
           ....
       }
}
```